# Node.js: How to disable colors in the console?

Tags: node.js, npm, console

Im new to node.js and are currently [playing around](https://gist.github.com/squadwuschel/c7529456ac42f45f2b255dd3c7030499) with npm.

I found that the console output is colored in a weird way on my System, i can only read it when i copypaste it into a text editor. Changing the background back to black and the font-color to white also did not help. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Node.js colored console output unreadable]

How can i disable those colors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disable colors in npm using the next command:

```
npm config set color false
```

---

Alternatively, create a new script inside of your `package.json` with the next format:

```
  "scripts": {
    "install": "npm install --no-color"
  }
```

And use it like this from the command line:

```
npm run install --save <your_package>
```

Comment: Added an update if that helps! Consider upvoting if the answer was useful to you :)

Comment: here you have ;-)

Comment: I have a command called "stage" and when I do "npm run stage --no-color" the switch did not have any effect. Am trying the config route now.

Answer (score 0):

And if you are running docker you can add the `NO_COLOR` **env varibale** with any value at statup

for example

```bash
docker run -e NO_COLOR=true node:lts
```